# Android HTTP calls not setting Accept-Language headers?

Tags: android, google-chrome, http-headers

I have set my Google Nexus 4 device to the `Français (France)` setting, and am browsing a site that is localized via the `Accept-Language` HTTP header from the client.

However, when I look at the `Accept-Language` settings arriving at the server, I see is is just `en-US`.

If I use the Dolphin browser to view the same site on the same device, the header comes in as `fr-FR,en-US;q=0.8`, and the site displays correctly in French.

The Nexus 4 is a development device, running Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H. The version of Chrome is 32.0.1700.99.

Does anyone know how I get Chrome to honor the device's Language setting?

I am developing an Android app, and was expecting that the HTTP client `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` would honor setting the `Accept-Language`HTTP header when calling my web service. However it doesn't, and I'm trying to figure out why.

The Chrome browser also exhibits this behavior, so I thought I would see if anyone else has this issue (posting my code is a little convoluted, and not really appropriate).

Do I really have to explicitly set the HTTP headers based on what I get back from `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` ?

It seems that is not the intent of being able to set the user's language via the Android settings.

Comment: This isn't a tech support forum, try another stack-exchange like http://android.stackexchange.com/ or google any documentation on chrome itself

Comment: I read through some of the Android.SE site questions. They seem more user focused than Dev focused. So I asked here. There are also several questions here on SO that are in a similar vein. Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems user focused! If you think its not meant to be then there's probably some other details you need to add that will clear up your queation, at the moment all iI can see is you're using two other peoples apps you've installed, that aren't things you've developed and they're not working

Comment: @NickCardoso: Thanks for the feedback! I'll reword and see if I can get a better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So are you doing the following steps? (I'd imagine from your question that you already are, but I want to check because this works for me)

```
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost(webServiceUrl);
  request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "fr");
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: That's the problem:  Do I really need to explicitly set the header?  Surely Chrome (and the default HTTP client) should read that information from the system, rather than assuming `en-US` ?

Comment: Well chrome is integrated with location settings so it's possible it's decided based on that (if you've left it enabled). I think you do need to explicitly add it for Http Client. If you've checked its default headers and that's wrong, have you checked what your default Locale returns for country? Perhaps the setting for language does not change the locale

Comment: Thanks again!  The location settings on or off didn't seem to do the trick, but you got me thinking: perhaps if I clear the Chrome cache that that might have an effect.  It did!  It seems to re-start Chrome from scratch and *then* it re-reads the system language settings and reloads things. Also, you are correct: it looks like the standard requests need to have the language explicitly set in the headers. Otherwise i just get `-` in the Apache web logs as the `Accept-Language` header.